# How to get tree of svg inserted to the DOM as text

Tags: text, svg, xmlnode

I have embeded svg that I created dynamicaly using ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'file.svg',
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(svg) {
    var svg = $(svg).appendTo('body');
    var shape = svg.find('g#shape');
    // how to get shape as text.
  }
});
```

How can I get svg Tree for instance a group with few paths as text the same as `html()` work in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XMLSerializer to serialise a node. Something like this...

```
var XMLS = new XMLSerializer(); 
var string = XMLS.serializeToString(node);
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your browser, it can use one of two serializer:

```
function xmltostring(domElem) { // Input the NODE of the DOM element
  if (window.XMLSerializer) { // FF, Chrome, IE10 has an internal serializer
    var XMLS = new XMLSerializer();
    var xmlString = XMLS.serializeToString(domElem);
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject){  // IE9 uses ActiveX
    var xmlString = domElem.xml;
  }
  return xmlString;
}
```

Note: Works on Safari too. IE8 and below cannot handle SVG natively (needs plugin), untested with this function.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, I wrote this plugin that return the text of SVG, probably will work with any xml embeded into html DOM.

```
$.fn.xml = function() {
    function serialize(node) {
        var i;
        var text = '<' + node.nodeName;
        for(i = 0; i < node.attributes.length; ++i) {
            text += ' ' + node.attributes[i].name + '="' +
                    node.attributes[i].value + '"';
        }
        text += '>';
        if (node.childNodes.length) {
            for (i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
                if (node.childNodes[i] instanceof Text) {
                    text += node.childNodes[i].wholeText
                } else if (node.childNodes[i] instanceof SVGElement) {
                    text += serialize(node.childNodes[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return text + '</' + node.nodeName + '>';;
    }
    return serialize(this[0]);   
};
```